# Inkscape not starting after installation on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, inkscape

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and I installed **Inkscape** via software center and it does not open after attempting to start.

On terminal I get after `inkscape`

```
inkscape: error while loading shared libraries: libgtkmm-2.4.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inkscape worked after running this command

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgtkmm-2.4-1v5:i386 libgtkmm-2.4-1v5
```

Comment: And here on Ubuntu 18.04, I had to do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libwpg-0.3 libwpd-0.10`. What's up with this package...